# Getting Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'

Tags: typescript

I am writing an import statement `import { PI } from './math/circle'` in *app.ts* file and have a constant `export const PI = 3.14` in *circle.ts* file but on running the program by doing `tsc app.ts --outFile app.js` keeps showing this error.

> error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.
>   1 export const PI = 3.14

But according to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) I am importing correctly. I have also tried changing the **"module": "commonjs"** to **"module": "amd"/"system"** and then reloading the VSCode windows but no luck. Where am I going wrong?

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "target": "es5",                         
    "module": "amd",                    
    "strict": true,                          
    "noImplicitAny": true,                
    "strictNullChecks": true,              
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**P.S: typescript version 3.5.3**

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `tsconfig.json` to be taken into account you have to invoque the tsc command with no input files, more details [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).
Running `tsc app.ts --outFile app.js` you are skipping your `tsconfig.json` and therefore you have to specify the module system manually so running `tsc app.ts --outFile app.js --module amd` should do the trick.

The other option as mentioned above is just to run `tsc --outFile app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) to bundle multiple typescript files into a single javascript file.